# Use url Link to specific CR number in Starteam

Tags: git, url, starteam

I'm working on migration from starteam to GIT.

Git will be used as verison control system. Right now the plan is to continue using starTeam as a issue tracker.

My goal is to parse the commit msg and find the CR number and then create a link in that commit to starteam CR

Example

```
Commit msg 
This commit solves CR #123
```

'#123' would be parsed to a link pointing into startteam using a Startteam URL

I have fixed so that GIT will complain if no CR number is added to a commit. 
But It would have been nice that that CR number added in commit msg could be a link to the specific issue(CR) in StarTeam
When I looking at the URL to a specific issue in Starteam I cannot see the connection to the CR number.

This is an URL to CR 3075....
`starteam://plan0542:49205/0;ns=Project;scheme=id/0;ns=View;scheme=id/80984;ns=ChangeRequest;scheme=id;scope=full`

How can i change this URL to point to right issue in startteam when I only have the CR number 3075?

Comment: I can only tell you that it is possible. I remember doing it at my last job. However, I don't have access to the source code so I can't tell you how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a text about it here: [Link](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/33315)

The solution ended up like this. Change to scheme=name

```
starteam://plan0542:49205/0;ns=Project;scheme=id/0;ns=View;scheme=id/3075;ns=ChangeRequest;scheme=name;scope=full``
```